# UITableView crashing on row selection

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

In my app I have a switch that determines how the tableView is to be populated. If one side is selected, it will display all items from an xml feed, whereas if the other side is selected, it will show only those that have been downloaded to the device. When first opening the app, it displays all items by default, and all rows can be selected with no problem, and when selecting to show the downloads, all can be selected without issue as well; however, when returning to "show all", if you select a table cell that is farther down, the app will crash. It will only crash if you select a row that is farther down that the number of items downloaded, so I suspect this has something to do with the numberOfRowsInSections call, but I cannot for the life of me seem to fix it!

Here is my code within that method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section         {

if (showDownloadsSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){

    rows = itemsToDisplay.count; 
}
else if (showDownloadsSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]
    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"downloads"];

    NSArray *fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path
   error:&error];
    rows = fileList.count;
}
return rows;
}
```

EDIT:

I was able to fix it after a little more inspection. Turns out I was checking for a file at [downloads objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] before ensuring the table was populated with downloads, rather than all items. Thanks to all for your help!

Comment: What is your exact error?

Comment: you should add your selection logic too. Looks like your `rows` variable is not declared locally...is this a member variable?

Comment: What line is it crashing on?  Please provide the exact error, and consider adding a stack trace.

Comment: Exact error: 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'  It will not always read "empty array", it will read however many item exist in my downloads array.

Comment: The 'rows' variable is an NSInteger I declared in the .h file and synthesized so it could be accessed from another method.

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't use a property to store rows. Make it a local variable. If you need to access the number of rows in the table outside the delegate method, run the logic again separately.

The fileList local variable, however, seems like it should be a property. You are referencing a simar array in the didSelectRowAtIndex method, right? Could there be a discrepancy there?

**Update:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

  self.itemsToDisplay      = ...
  self.fileList            = ...
  self.showDownloadsSwitch = ...

  [self.showDownloadsSwitch addTarget:self.tableView
                               action:@selector(reloadData)
                     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if (section == 0 && self.showDownloadsSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    return self.itemsToDisplay.count;

  if (section == 1 && self.showDownloadsSwitch.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    return self.fileList.count;

  return 0;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (indexPath.section == 0)
    [self.itemsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  else
    [self.fileList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: That is the only place the fileList variable is used, I use a separate array that is a property, but instantiated with the same logic in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. If there was a discrepancy, would it actually cause this particular problem? I seems to me that the problem is the table accessing this array when, according to my code, it should be accessing the other array for all feed items. It seems to be able to switch from the first row count to the second the first time the option is switched, but unable to go back to the first row count...

Comment: Your error indicates that you're trying to access an index (the row) from an array that has a different number of items in it than you expect. I just updated the answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try including this one.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] init];
    return view;
}
```

It will not allow to show further rows to be selected if second choice is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I think your array is empty let try below scenario

```
NSArray *fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path
   error:&error];
if(fileList)
{
    rows = fileList.count;
}
else
{
 // handle your error
}
```